# Can I look through a directory's subdirectories and copy a file of a certain extension to a new folder?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, command-line, terminal, cmd.exe

Newbie here- 
I have this terminal script that doesn't seem to work on Windows to search through subdirectories in a directory for all files with a certain extension and move these to a new directory.

```
find ./ -name '*.xlsx' -exec cp -prv '{}' \Documents\...' ";"
```

I was wondering if the same thing could be done using a MATLAB or any other way in Windows script. My ultimate goal is to amalgamate the data in all of these xlsx files into one file. 
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: does it have to be a Matlab script? you can do this easily with cmd.exe

Comment: @mael' doesn't have to be MATLAB, I was trying to do this using cmd and it wouldn't work. How can I do it?

Comment: posted answer that should work for you; let me know if you have any issues with it.

Comment: @mael' just did it and nothing happened - no errors but nothing showed up in the output directory. Are the "< >" necessary when writing the name or just the directory name, sorry I am very new to this.

Comment: it's no problem - no you don't need the brackets, that was just the way of saying "insert here". your script will look like: for /r "C:\Your\Directory" %A in (*.xlsx) do (move /y "%A" "C:\New\Directory\%~nxA" - i'll edit the answer to make stuff more clear

Comment: @mael' It works!!! Amazing thank you!! Does batch solution mean that this can be made and run in MATLAB?

Comment: No problem, I'm happy to help. I'm not familiar with MATLAB but from seeing other posts here on superuser I would lean toward yes. My best advice if you want to test anything like this would be to simply make your "do" command something like (echo %%A) to see if the loop does what you want before you try telling it to move/modify stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop through a directory in cmd.exe:

```
for /r "C:\Your\Directory" %A in (*.xlsx) do (move /y "%A" "C:\New\Directory\%~nxA")
```

The `/r` in `FOR` loops through all files rooted in the given directory. The `/y` in `move` suppresses a prompt that asks you if moving the file is OK. Using quotes around file/directory paths is best practice in case there are spaces. This will loop through subfolders by default.

Reference: [FOR Looping commands](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

If you fancy a batch solution I prefer setting it up with variables like this:

```
@echo off

set "old=C:\Your\Directory"
set "new=C:\New\Directory"

for /r "%old%" %%A in (*.xlsx) do (
    move /y "%%A" "%new%\%%~nxA"
)

pause
```

The main difference (in my opinion) comparing batch to plain command-line is that it's a bit easier to tweak when you can just go back and edit a variable without having to potentially change a path multiple times in the same file. Also note that your parameter `%A` gets changed to `%%A` in a batch file.

Comment: `for /R` also iterates through sub-directories, so there could occur collisions since the `move` command moves all files into the new root directory and does not regard the old directory hierarchy...